# Is Hamilton's principle compatible with the relativity principle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, relativity, variational-principle, action

The principle of Hamilton in classical mechanics is a fundamental one. It states that the real trajectory of a particle extremize the action

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} d \tau  L (q , \dot{q}, \tau )  . $$

In this formalism, time has a different status than space.

The problem is then, is it compatible with relativity?

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, the [stationary action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), 
   $$\delta S~=~0,\tag{1}$$
   also known as the [Hamilton's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton's_principle)$^1$ (where 
   $$S~=~\int \! \mathrm{d}t~ L, \qquad L~=~\int \! \mathrm{d}^3x~{\cal L},  \tag{2}$$ 
   is the Lagrangian action functional) can be manifestly Lorentz covariant and/or manifestly generally covariant, if the underlying theory respects these symmetries.
2. Concerning relativistic point particles, there exist stationary action principles with manifestly reparametrization invariant world-line parameter, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44947/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45922/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107921/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137857/2451), & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114862/2451) Phys.SE posts and links therein.

__

$^1$ Despite the name, the Hamilton's principle is part of the Lagrangian (rather than the Hamiltonian) formulation. Concerning the relativistic status of Hamitonian formulations, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38286/2451) related Phys.SE post and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

There are ways to cram relativity into this formalism, but they're awkward, convoluted, and rarely used.

The much more common approach is to replace the Lagrangian with a Lagrangian *density* - a functional on *fields* $\mathcal{L}(\partial_\mu \varphi, \varphi, x, t)$, where $\partial_\mu \varphi$ denotes a partial derivative of the field $\varphi(x, t)$ with respect to the variable $\mu$, which ranges over $x, y, z,$ and $t$.  The Lagrangian density is a Lorentz-scalar field and therefore Lorentz-invariant.  In principle, the Lagrangian $L(t)$ itself is a spatial integral of the Lagrangian density ($L(t) = \int d^3x\ \mathcal{L}(x, t)$), and the action $S$ is the time integral of the Lagrangian as usual ($S = \int dt\, L(t)$).  But the Lagrangian $L$ is frame-dependent, so in practice it's much nicer conceptually to go right from the Lagrangian density to the action by integrating over *spacetime* ($S = \int d^3x\ dt\ \mathcal{L}(x, t)$) - it turns out that this integral is Lorentz-invariant.  So everything is expressed in terms of local, Lorentz-covariant fields, and space and time derivatives and integrals are treated on equal footing.

For example, a common Lagrangian density for a relativistic scalar field $\varphi(x, t)$ is
$$ \mathcal{L}(\partial_\mu \varphi, \varphi) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\mu = x, y, z, t} \partial_\mu \varphi \partial^\mu \varphi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \varphi^2.$$
In relativistic quantum field theory, the excitations of this scalar field correspond to particles with a mass given by the parameter $m$.

Answer (score 1):

For field theory, you must instead use the Lagrangian density 
$$S=\int_\Omega d^4x \mathcal L (\phi,\partial \phi)\;.$$
(You may add also $\partial \partial \phi$)

In curved spacetime it generalized to
$$S[\phi]=\int_\Omega d^4x \sqrt{-g} \mathcal L (\phi,\partial \phi)\equiv \int_\Omega d^4x \tilde {\mathcal L} (\phi,\partial \phi)\;,$$
where tilde indicate that it is a scalar density. The Euler-Lagrange eqn reads
$$ \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \phi} - \nabla_\mu(\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial {\nabla_\mu\phi}}) =0\;.$$

For the gravitational field $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ the action is
$$S[g_{\mu\nu}]=\int_\Omega d^4x \sqrt{-g} \mathcal L (g,\partial g)=\frac{c^3}{8 \pi G}\int_\Omega d^4x \sqrt{-g} R$$