# Equivalent of the geodesic equation for fields

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, spacetime

Mass tells spacetime how to curve using the Einstein field equations and spacetime tells mass how to move using the geodesic equation.

The effect of the electromagnetic field on space-time is given by the Einstein field equation. But what equation gives the effect of spacetime curvature on the electromagnetic field? Is there no replacement of the geodesic equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maxwell's equations (albeit in curved spacetime).

The geodesic equation is, in some sense, just the equations of motion you get for a massive point-particle coupled to the gravitational field. The action would read
$$S = S_{EH} + m \int \sqrt{-\frac{\mathrm{d} x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\frac{\mathrm{d} x^\nu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} g_{\mu\nu}} \mathrm{d}\tau,$$
and varying the action leads to the Einstein equations and to the geodesic equation (there are issues with self-field corrections, but I won't dive into that in here).

For the electromagnetic field, you'll have a similar setup, but the additional term in the action will be the action for the electromagnetic field. In the end of the day, you'll get to Maxwell's equations, which read
\begin{align}
\nabla_a F^{ab} &= - 4 \pi j^b, \\
\nabla_{[a}F_{bc]} &= 0,
\end{align}
in Gaussian units. See, e.g., Wald's *General Relativity*, Sec. 4.3.

For other field contents, one would replace Maxwell's equations with the equations of motion for the field in question. A scalar field has the Klein–Gordon equation, spin-1/2 fields have the Dirac equation, and so on.

Comment: May I ask you a related question? How does the action from your first equation apply to massless particles?

Comment: @LibertarianFeudalistBot It would be best to keep each post to a single question, since it makes it easier to navigate the site. Nevertheless, the action would need to be different. It is discussed in the accepted answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331529/168783

Comment: But don't Maxwell's eqns describe the behavior of *free* EM fields? How can the same eqns describe the *response* of the EM field in interaction with spacetime curvature?

Comment: @RyderRude In the answer, the Maxwell equations use covariant derivative of curved spacetime. It is not the Maxwell equations in flat spacetime.

Comment: @RyderRude It is precisely what Libertarian Feudalist Bot said. In addition, I believe I should mention that while one *can* solve Maxwell's equations in a previously given curved spacetime (hence not considering the backreaction of the EM field in the spacetime itself, which is valid for weak fields), the consistent (but often difficult) way of doing it would be to solve Einstein's equations and Maxwell's equations simultaneously, as a coupled system of PDEs.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Whoa. solving that must involve doing some nightmare math?? How would you rate that in terms of toughness?

Comment: @RyderRude I don't really know how to answer lol. I haven't worked much with solutions to Einstein-Maxwell. The case for a charged spherical black hole, though, is fairly similar to deriving the Schwarzschild solution. I guess it depends a lot on how much symmetry you are assuming